# FileNotFoundException when mocking camera intent result

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, filenotfoundexception, android-camera-intent

I am trying to improve an integration test that triggers the camera app. However, I am intercepting the intent and I want to use a dummy image in the integration test.

Therefore, I have this code in my test (relevant part):

```
@Test
public void runCameraTest() {
//...
IntentCallback intentCallback = intent -> {
            if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE")) {
                try {
                    Uri imageUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT);
                    Log.d(TAG, "runCameraTest: imageUri: "+imageUri);
                    Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
                    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                            context.getResources(),
                            R.drawable.example_photo);
                    OutputStream out = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getContentResolver().openOutputStream(imageUri);
                    icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"runCameraTest-Exception: " + e.getMessage(),e);
                }
            }
        };

        IntentMonitorRegistry.getInstance().addIntentCallback(intentCallback);

        Intents.intending(IntentMatchers.hasAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)).respondWith(
                new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null));

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        cameraView.perform(click());

        Intents.release();

        Intents.init();
//...
}
```

And the camera intent is built using the following method (not sure if we need all the SDK if statements, this was written by another developer):

```
private Intent getCameraIntent() {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {

            try {
                mTempImageFile = File.createTempFile(
                        TEMP_CAMERA_IMAGE_FILE_NAME,  /* prefix */
                        "." + TEMP_CAMERA_IMAGE_FILE_EXT,         /* suffix */
                        getCurrentContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)      /* directory */
                );
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                Crashlytics.logException(ex);
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (mTempImageFile != null) {
                mTempImageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getCurrentContext(),
                        getCurrentContext().getString(R.string.content_provider),
                        mTempImageFile);
            }

        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues(1);
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg");
            mTempImageUri = getCurrentContext().getContentResolver()
                    .insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        } else {
            File outputFile = new File(getStoragePath()
                    + File.separator + TEMP_CAMERA_IMAGE_FILE);

            mTempImageUri = Uri.fromFile(outputFile);
        }

        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mTempImageUri);
        return cameraIntent;
    }
```

I am running this test in Amazon Device Farm and this works for some devices (Android 7, 8 and 9) but it fails in a Samsung Galaxy S6 (Android 6.0.1) and Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 (Android 4.4.2).

The error is a `java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory` raised on line `OutputStream out = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getContentResolver().openOutputStream(imageUri);`

The log shows that the `imageUri` is `content://media/external/images/media/8244`

Does anyone has an idea on what could be the problem? Could it be something related to the fact that the device doesn't have an SD Card? (not sure if that is the case)

Answer (score 0):

>= API level `N`, you'd ordinary have to use a `FileProvider` to resolve the `Uri`:

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.acme.fileprovider", outputFile);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
```

when <= API level `M` fails, this means the `elseif` and `else` branches fail to resolve the `Uri`.

debugging on local emulators might be helpful to determine why it doesn't work remotely.

Comment: I am not sure if it is related to the SDK version, because when I run the test in my local device (Samsung Galaxy Tab S - Android 6.0.1) the test runs successfully... Can it be related with the SD card?